# In F#, How can I cast a function to a different delegate?

Tags: f#, delegates

I need to cast a function with the signature `Thing -> Thing -> int` to a `Comparison<Thing>`.

For example, when I have:

```
Array.Sort(values, mySort)
```

I get an error stating "**This expression was expected to have type Comparison but here has type Thing -> Thing -> int**"

When I try this:

```
Array.Sort(values, (fun (a, b) -> mySort a b))
```

(actually, this is by way of a wrapper object)

I get an error stating "**Type constraint mismatch. The type ''a -> 'b' is not compatible with the type 'Comparison'**"

How am I supposed to provide a `Comparison<T>`?

FYI: `Comparison<T>` is a delegate with the signature `'T * 'T -> int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
let values = [|1;2;3|]
let mySort a b = 0
Array.Sort(values, mySort)
```

But have you tried:

```
Array.Sort(values, Comparison(mySort))
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, despite the fact that delegate signatures are expressed in tupled form (e.g. `'T * 'T -> int`), you need to provide your function in curried form (e.g. `fun a b -> mySort a b`).  See [section 6.4.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597457) of the spec.

Comment: It looks like he's doing that since the signature is `Thing -> Thing -> int`.